# Spring framework replacement for FlowAction

Tags: spring, jsp, struts, spring-webflow

I recently inherited a *very* old code base (written in 2006) that uses the spring framework.  Right now, the goal is to get it semi-functional, which I've almost done.  However, there is some code I can't seem to fix that uses the class "FlowAction" from 'org.springframework.webflow.executor.struts.FlowAction'.  This used to exist in the spring-webflow-1.0.6.jar, but no longer exists in 2.4.2.

Can anyone give me any hints for how to fix the following code using more recent spring framework code?

```
<action path="/secure/FRONT/enrollAction"
        name="webflowActionForm" scope="request"
        type="org.springframework.webflow.executor.struts.FlowAction" />
```

Please keep in mind that this is an attempt to get this *very* old code working so telling me it's impossible is fine, but please provide a good reason why (I'm no spring expert).  I've googled and searched the spring code to no avail, but I'm hoping it's as simple as using a different library.  Thanks for any input!

**EDIT**

Based on the first comment below, struts is no longer supported.  I am offering a bounty for someone who knows how to update this code.  I assume an alternative exists, or was offered by the spring framework, for code that was using the old libraries.  If anyone knows what that is, I would greatly appreciate it.  I just need help on how I would update the specific block of code above and am happy to provide any further information needed.

Comment: There is no  more struts support in web flow and as that class is part of that support it will not be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the info, @M.Deinum.  I guess I need to start looking for a replacement to the structs framework.

Comment: There is no replacement and no support is available anymore. You would need to upgrade the struts version and use struts 2 and write the Struts web flow integration yourself.

Comment: Your best bet would be to upgrade your struts actions to spring request mapped methods and remove the dependency on FlowAction. As a side note, struts 1 framework reached end of life status in April of 2013. It is probably better to refactor struts 1 out of the project anyway.

Comment: Thanks again M.Deinum and thank you @jjhavokk. I wish I could say I was surprised by your answers, but code this old is likely to have these problems.  I'm a bit over my head here so it may be time to hire a freelancer who can move this forward. Your comments have been helpful. Thanks!

Comment: why don't you use spring mcv? you 'll have to modify also the jsp files.

Answer (score 0):

```
FlowHandlerMapping 
FlowHandler
FlowHandlerAdapter
FlowExecutor
FlowDefinition 
FlowRegistry
```

we can use the following classes for getting struts functionality to your code